# how to change old magento 2 installation keys from VS code editor?

Tags: magento2

I have removed public and private keys from magento account which was configured in visual studio code.After deleting keys from magento account i am updating composer from already installed magento throwing error. credentials are not matched.

How can i change new keys in visual studio code for magento installation via composer.

Help

Comment: which OS you are using ?

Comment: @Pawan windows 10

Comment: You can search `composer/auth.json` file and change your credential!